# How can I determine max memory usage of a process in Linux?

Tags: linux, memory-management

I have a program that's running in two different modes.  I want to compare the two modes with regard to runtime and memory requirements.  Determining runtime is easy with using `time`.  In fact, in this case it's *really* easy because the program reports both the CPU time and the wallclock time at the end of the test.  However, determining memory usage is a bit harder.

How can I get details of the memory usage of the process throughout its lifetime?  I want to know both the maximum usage and the average.  In fact, ideally I'd like some graph of memory usage throughout the life of the run.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Valgrind's massif tool can give you a chart of memory usage over time.  See http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html

Comment: Absolute gold for measuring stuff. It even shows you a timed graph!

Answer (score 36):

#### `time` has a verbose mode which gives you the maximum and average resident set size.

(The resident set size is the portion of a process's memory that is held in RAM).

```
$ /usr/bin/time -v command_that_needs_to_measured |& grep resident
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 6596
    Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
```

Remember to use the binary `/usr/bin/time`, which has a `-v` option. You can view its documentation by running `man time`. If you fail to specify its path, bash's built-in `time` will run instead, which *doesn't* have a `-v` option. You can view its documentation in the bash man page or by running `help time`.